# Both Veritcal and Horizontal Scrollview

Tags: android, scroll, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I am using a table that needs both vertical and horizontal scrolling. I used two scroll view to do so as below. Is it possible to use single one for both purposes? Meaning enable one scrollview as horizontal and vertical:

```
LinearLayout contentView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.contentView);
TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());
TableRow tableRow;
TextView textView;

    for (int i = 0; i <28; i++) {
    tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
    for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
        textView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textView.setText("test");
        textView.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
        tableRow.addView(textView);
    }
    tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
}
ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(MainActivity.this);
scroll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                     LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
scroll.addView(tableLayout);
HorizontalScrollView horizontalScroll = new HorizontalScrollView(MainActivity.this);
horizontalScroll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                                 LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
horizontalScroll.addView(scroll);
contentView.addView(horizontalScroll);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Use the custom scroll view code that you can use in your xml file.
This is one small sample for Vertical Scroll View in this you can use Horizontal also

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class VerticalScrollview extends ScrollView {

    public VerticalScrollview(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public VerticalScrollview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public VerticalScrollview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.i("VerticalScrollview",
                    "onInterceptTouchEvent: DOWN super false");
            super.onTouchEvent(ev);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            return false; // redirect MotionEvents to ourself

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            Log.i("VerticalScrollview",
                    "onInterceptTouchEvent: CANCEL super false");
            super.onTouchEvent(ev);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onInterceptTouchEvent: UP super false");
            return false;

        default:
            Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onInterceptTouchEvent: " + action);
            break;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onTouchEvent. action: " + ev.getAction());
        return true;
    }
}
```